# If $F=ma$ does that mean objects traveling at cosntant speeds have no force?

Tags: forces, mass, acceleration, collision

If, say an Elephant (3,500 KG) crashed into me at a constant velocity just under Light Speed(299,792,457m/s, 0m/s^2) would I be subject to no force? If so what would cause me to be hurt in the impact?

Comment: Since your velocity will likely change due to such an unlucky encounter, it means that a force has been imparted on you. More accurately, your momentum has changed. Momentum is mass times velocity, and the more general form of Newton's second law reads: $F = \frac{d(mv)}{dt}$ , so when $v$ changes it definitely indicates a force. The elephant's momentum will also change by the same amount, but since it has a bigger mass it's easy to see it will slow down much less than you'll speed up.

Comment: What do you think just under light speed has to do with this?

Comment: The elephant's kinetic energy (relative to you) is ~12242.21 times its rest energy.

Answer (score 2):

It means that in order for the elephant to remain at that velocity, the vector sum of all forces on the object must be zero, not that there are no forces on it.

By specifying constant velocity, there must be additional forces on the elephant.  Those forces summed with the forces from your impact must be zero.

Instead imagine the scenario: an elevator cab is moving upward in an elevator shaft at a constant 2m/s.  Are the forces on the elevator zero?

We know gravity is pulling down on the elevator cab, so we imagine that there must be forces from the cables pulling up on the cab that exactly balance the weight (plus a bit more to overcome drag).  There are real forces on the cab, but the vector sum is zero.

Answer (score 1):

If an elephant, mass $3500\,\rm kg$, running at $7\,\rm m/s\,(=25 km/hr)$ hits you then there must be an interaction between you and the elephant.
In other words the elephant exerts a force on you and you speed up and you exert a force on the elephant and it slows down - this is Newton's third law.
Now because your mass, say $50\,\rm kg$ is so much less than that of the elephant, the elephant speed will not change very much.
Now suppose that you started from rest and as the elephant hit you, you managed to cling on the elephant and ended up travelling at approximately $7\,\rm m/s$ then your momentum (mass $\times$ velocity) has changed from zero (not moving) to $50\times 7=350\,\rm \,kg\,m/s$.
An important consideration is how long it took you to change your speed from $0\,\rm m/s$ to $7\,\rm m/s$ and let's assume that it was $0.05\,\rm s$.

The force which the elephant exerted on you was $\dfrac{\text{change in momentum}}{\text{time taken for the change}} = \dfrac{350-0}{0.05} = 7000\,\rm newtons.$
Your weight is approximately $50 \times 10 = 500 \,\rm N$ and so the elephant exerted on you a force which is fourteen times your weight.
The damage done to you (and the elephant) depends on numerous factors, eg which part of your body first hit the elephant, how strong your bones are etc, but note that at the speed of the elephant that you quoted in your question I think that both of you would come to an unfortunate end.

[On the Physics of the Bone Fracture](http://ysu.am/files/Bone-Fracture.pdf)